# Displaying svg image without extension in HTML

Tags: html, image, apache, svg

So I've been searching arount if it's okay to **save and display images without extension**. And from what I've found browsers are intelligent and there should be no problem doing so. However I'm facing a problem when trying to display an **SVG image without extension** using `img` tag.

> **TL;DR;**
>
> I **need to display PNG/JPG/.../SVG images without extension** using this syntax `<img src="images/image" alt="Avatar" />` And for **SVG image** this is **not working**. I have two servers, on one I'm using **Apache 2.4** and on the second one **nginx**. I'm using the newest version of Chrome on Windows 10.

**What have I tried and found out:**

If the image is **PNG/JPG/...** without extension it **works just fine** as it does with the extension and the extension does not even need to match the actual type.

Displays an PNG image that has no extension
`<img src="images/image" alt="Avatar" />` . 
Displays an PNG image that has PNG extension
`<img src="images/image.png" alt="Avatar" />` . 
Displays an PNG image that has JPG extension
`<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Avatar" />`

However when trying to do the same with **SVG**. None from the above works. The **only** way it **works** is using the **SVG extension**:

`<img src="images/image.svg" alt="Avatar" />`

I've found that the problem is that the **response from Apache server does not contain the "Content-Type" header** in case there is no extension. And I've found out that the **Content-Type is provided by mod_mime** which does it using the extension. And there seems to be no way to do it through the **actual MIME by reading first few bytes of the file**.

In case there is no Content-Type browser seems to automatically set some image type probably because of the img tag. However in case of svg it is not being decoded properly and nothing is displayed.

Interesting is that if I open the file in the **browser's tab** the **svg image is displayed properly** even without extension. So I think that the browser reads the MIME info only if the file is opened seperately and if it's linked by img tag there is some lazy difference.

I've also tried setting some another default Content-Type using .htaccess, because sbd suggested trying that:

```
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType image/svg+xml
</FilesMatch>
```

With this svg without extension displayed however normal images didn't.

```
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType application/unknown
</FilesMatch>
```

Images worked but svg didn't.

**Why I need it like this:**

I'm running **PHP/MySQL** and I save multiple images like user **avatars, forum images** etc. I save them as some **unique number** (user ID, post ID) **without extension**. So it's easy for me to find them.

**The actual question:**

Is it possible to do this somehow? If not what is the proper way to **handle SVG compatibility**? Should I save images with extensions and store the extension infromation into the database? Or is there some another way?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the URL has no extension, but the actual files do?

Comment: No, sorry if I failed in explaining. I was trying to point on the ways that I've tried. The actual files have no extension and I want to be able to display them. I though that browser will automatically check the MIME type from the file but in case of linking svg without extension via img tag it does not work. And I wanna know what are my options to display both normal images and svg images.

Comment: There is a [mod_mime_magic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) for Apache.

Comment: @ccprog Thanks for the link! By default it returns `text/plain` in content-type header, but I've been able to fix that by adding `0   string      \<svg       image/svg+xml` into apache/conf/magic file. However I'm wondering if there is a reason they don't do this by default like some performance impact?

Comment: Edit: I see that they even write there about some performance issues, so I'm unsure if I should use this as I wanna use that on a website with bigger trafic. So maybe it might be better idea to do it by storing the extension info. Can you help me find some more information or are you familiar with this problem as it is kinda hard for me to find something about that.